# Where should I put CoyoteBot?

Tags: discussion

Recently I made a fork of WolfBot called CoyoteBot. While I know Kaz asked a similar question [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/16140/595510), I want to know what to do about CoyoteBot.

terdon did not like it in the General Room or Ubuntu Regulators. Where should I put it?

> **Update: The bot now has a simple AI and can answer questions if programmed to do so.**

Comment: please explain what CoyoteBot will do (in particular, how is your question different from the linked one - how is CoyoteBot different from WolfBot?) Also it was not only terdon, but many others, who had objections to putting bots in any chatroom :)

Comment: Please note that the moderator team here is currently discussing how we wish to proceed with this.  We will provide an official statement on this soon, once we've come to a decision on how this should proceed.

Comment: @Zanna what if it is my own chatroom?

Comment: @MarkYisri we have no issues with you having your bot in your own room, however we are focused more or less on the issue of the "main rooms" like the General room or the Regulators channel, and have to discuss that further.

Comment: @ThomasWard I see. Should we open a chat room for this discussion?

Comment: if it is in its own room doing useful things that require user interaction, then as I said to Kaz, I will happily visit that room regularly and supply the needed user interaction... I much prefer that :)

Comment: @Zanna okay: visit [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47256/the-coyotes-den).

Comment: @MarkYisri No, we don't need a chat room for this discussion at this time.

Comment: Terdon didn't express an opinion one way or the other. What I said was that if you want to add a bot to a public room, you need to open a meta discussion first. Yes I , personally, don't like the idea of bots. However, if others like it, then fine. My main point is that you shouldn't just add a bot to a room and especially not the site's main room without a discussion to see if the other users want it.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, but it is the wrong question. First you need to explain what your bot does. What does it offer? Why would anyone want to have it in any room? Then, after explaining what it does, ask if people want it and then, after establishing that some users want it, then you can decide where.

Comment: A key question I have is what value any of these bots add.  Based on the existing features I see no added value currently to the bot.  In fact I see avenues for abuse leading to moderator flags and kickbans.  I see no difference in this request here than in Kaz's original request, because there's no real difference in bot functions.

Comment: I also agree with Terdon - you need to gauge community wants and needs too.

Comment: well @terdon, I don't know exactly what it will do yet. So should I keep it in my room for now?

Comment: @MarkYisri That would be a good idea especially if it's available functions are not decided upon yet

Comment: Okay @ThomasWard. So should I close this question?

Comment: @MarkYisri I see no harm in leaving it for now, in case you decide to edit it and include a feature list in the future.

Comment: Personally, I don't have enough information to form an opinion. If you go so far as to provide information such as requested by Zanna and Terdon that could change, as it is there's really not enough here to work with.