# Simple question has surprisingly high votes and views

Tags: discussion

I don't know what is special about this question: [Use sleep with minutes and seconds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064484/use-sleep-with-minutes-and-seconds)

This question is about the use of a basic shell function, can anyone explain to me what is difficult about a command like that (for which we only need read a little of the manual, like we say: RTFM!)?

This question has more views and more votes than some others that are more better and more instructive, so I didn't expect a success like that.

NB: I know this question won't be well received, but I really need explanation for this

Comment: More people understand the simple stuff and can make use of it, so it is more popular. If you are answering obscure questions that are hard to understand, less people will be interested. Never tell people RTFM, that is just sillyin the context of a site like this that is supposed to help people by answering their questions.

Comment: @MarkKirby i got sometimes reply like "Get a book" or something of same type on SO for something less obvious, that's why I don't understand; if tomorrow I ask a question like "How to open a file with Libreoffice in command line", will it be downvoted because too obvious, or upvoted because people know the answer?

Comment: The people who told you that are idiots, this is a problem with SO and is related to its size but it is not a accepted thing to do here, this site is much smaller and focused. People come here for small solutions just like that question and vote them up because they are useful to them, look here and see the most voted questions: https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=votes

Comment: " if tomorrow I ask a question like "How to open a file with Libreoffice in command line..." No your question would of got almost 30 up votes https://askubuntu.com/questions/659741/how-to-open-a-file-with-libreoffice-writer-from-terminal

Comment: Okay now I understand, I was feared to ask too obvious question because of my first on SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50511009/c-reprint-text-in-terminal-with-carriage-return (but that guy which said me "Get a book" removed his comment, not the downvote)

Comment: Due to some initial high upvotes, [that question got into the Hot Network Questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MdMO.png) that is shown on the right sidebar of all SE sites and thus it got more attention. Most users coming from HNQ can only upvote due to association rep. bonus, but cannot downvote, thus skewing the votes more.

Comment: What is the meaning of RTFM?

Comment: @CristianaNicolae https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM

Comment: @pomsky Thank you!

Comment: @damadam "... *reply like "Get a book" or something of same type on SO* ..." -- Ask Ubuntu is [generally considered to be friendlier than SO](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15826/is-the-ask-ubuntu-community-generally-more-friendly-than-stack-overflow-if-so) ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Confounding factors<sup>*</sup> aside, questions (and answers) like this tend to have long term popularity *because* people are trying to find a solution to the same problem. What *you* might think too obvious, or solved by `man whatever`, other people turn to Google (et al) as the first port of call.

Our goal is to *answer* questions so just telling them to look it up elsewhere isn't welcome. If that happens to you, flag it. Seriously, RTFM answers (and comments) have no place here.

That's not to say we're against people improving themselves. A really good answer won't stop at answering the question, it'll tell you how to answer questions like that in the future.

---

<sup>*</sup> Questions like this might be *initially* popular because people like low-hanging fruit. Some of the more simple things also tend to be solvable in a variety of ways and people like a good round of Code Golf and it's also a great way to learn advanced things you thought you already knew.

The [people with a Gold](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/182/command-line) in [command-line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/command-line) are fine specimens of low fruit eaters :)